# Why does processing a list file with a space in list file name fail in FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file

I'm redirecting `findstr` results to a text file. Next I'm deleting the files with the names written to the text file, but I am having an issue.

If the `findstr` results file has a space in file name, none of the files in the results file are deleted in the `FOR` loop. But if the list file created by `findstr` has a file name without a space in name, the `FOR` loop works as expected and deletes all files listed in the text file.

This code is deleting files which contain "Trojan" as a string.

```
findstr /s /m "Trojan" "C:\*.*">>"C:\result.txt" 2>nul 
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\result.txt) do del "%%i"
```

But this code is not deleting the files listed in the results text file.

```
findstr /s /m "Trojan" "C:\*.*">>"C:\result 2.txt" 2>nul 
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\result 2.txt) do del "%%i"
```

The result text file has a space in its name.

What is wrong on my second code with result text file having a space in file name?

Answer (score 1):

File names with spaces should generally be enclosed within quotes. But `FOR /F ... IN("string") DO ...` is treated as a string instead of a file name. There is a simple solution that is obvious if you carefully read the HELP. From the command line:

```
help for
```

or

```
for /?
```

The relevant section is

```
   usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
                     where a back quoted string is executed as a
                     command and a single quoted string is a
                     literal string command and allows the use of
                     double quotes to quote file names in
                     file-set.
```

So all you need is:

```
findstr /s /m "Trojan" "C:\*.*">>"C:\result 2.txt" 2>nul 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\result 2.txt") do del "%%i"
```

Comment: +1 because I apparently never really read the usebackq in detail /blush.  I knew it handled the command and used it as such, but not the file names which needed quoting.  Thanks for that and using an example which didn't use a command.